# coordinates after zoom in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, zooming

I am trying to draw circle after zoom and it's not drawn in correct place. With out zoom it is working fine. Do we need to consider any factors after zoom ? Some thing like scale factor .
Radius of the circle also increasing.
I need to draw correctly even after zoom also.

```
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
      WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);
          ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
      view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

             if (isZoomRequired == false)  //draw circle when zoom is off.
             {
             x = (int) rawEvent.getX();
                 y = (int) rawEvent.getY();
                 r = SettingsActivity.brushsize;

                pcanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
                layers[1] = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            view.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

            }
            else    //zoom when zoom is on or button selected                      
            {
             // Handle touch events here...
             switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               savedMatrix.set(matrix);
               start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
               Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
               mode = DRAG;
             break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
               oldDist = spacing(event);
               Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
               if (oldDist > 10f) {
               savedMatrix.set(matrix);
               midPoint(mid, event);
               mode = ZOOM;
               Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
               }
             break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
               mode = NONE;
               Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
             break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
               if (mode == DRAG) {
                 // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);
               }
               else if (mode == ZOOM) {
               float newDist = spacing(event);
               Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
               if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
               }
             }
             break;
         }


         view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

         }
     }
```

How to calculate x, y coordinates after zoom in android? and also radius of the circle after zoom.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from your code exactly what you're doing. But you have complete control over how you draw the circle.  You can either scale the radius of the circle based on the given zoom level and redraw the circle with the new radius or scale the matrix of the canvas based on the zoomlevel.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am trying to  draw a circle after zoom. But after zoom I am not able to draw at correct point.Is there any formula to calculate x, y coordinates after zoom using zoom level? With out zoom I am able to draw at correct point. After zoom I am not to draw at correct point. Kindly let me know how to calculate x , y coordinates after zoom and also radius of circle.

Comment: Now I am setting the matrix to canvas using below line  pcanvas.setMatrix(matrix); . But there is some improvement but still problem exist.

Comment: Hi Pavan do you find the solution for this.pls post the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener class you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector){ 
   //the focal point before taking into account the zoom/translations/etc  
    float startX = detector.getFocusX();
    float startY = detector.getFocusY();

    initialPoints = new float[]{startX, startY};
        if(transformMatrix.invert(inverseTransformMatrix))
            inverseTransformMatrix.mapPoints(initialPoints );
      //initialPoints now contain the correct points based on the current zoom
}
```